# Woocommerce 'Lost Password' is not working

Tags: woocommerce

I am using the version 2.1.12 of Woocommerce  and I'm having trouble getting the password reset to work.  Using a test customer account, I use the 'Lost Password' link, and once I've entered my address I receive the e-mail.  Only problem is the link in the email just takes me to password reset page , after entering the new password , it doesn't get saved, still the login works with old-password.

Comment: Upgrade WooCommerce. (Don't forget to make a backup though and use a test server if you can) Also test against a default theme. You need to isolate where the problem is coming from.

Comment: I have the same problem! Did you figure it out?